Template deduction guide doesn't work well with aggregate initialization
I am studying how to use deduction guides. I composed this program.
template<typename T>
struct Test {
    void f() {
        cout << std::is_same_v<T, std::size_t> << endl;
    }
    T t;
};

Test(int) -> Test<std::size_t>;

int main() {
    Test t1(1.2);
    t1.f();
}

I expected the deduction guide will only kick in when if I pass an integer to the aggregate initialization. Since I pass 1.2, I expected T will be deducted to double which won't triggered the deduction guide. However the output is 1, i.e. T -> int -> size_t.
I tried to add a constructor to the struct.
template<typename T>
struct Test {
    void f() {
        cout << std::is_same_v<T, std::size_t> << endl;
    }
    Test(T v): t(v) {}
    T t;
};

Test(int) -> Test<std::size_t>;

int main() {
    Test t1(1.2);
    t1.f();
}

The output was 0 which matched my previous expectation. Comparing these two programs, the only difference here is how the struct got initialized. What does the deduction guide not work well with the aggregate initialization? Thanks.

"I expected T will be deducted to double" You added a hypothetical constructor with an int parameter, which can be generally called with a double argument. Deduction is based on the existence of this constructor as well (it is not done "before").

" What does the deduction guide not work well with the aggregate initialization?..." Test t1(1.2); is not aggregate initialization so you're expectation and understanding of initialization is wrong in the first place.

@user12002570 Technically not, but it is practically equivalent in OP's case since C++20 due to p0960.

@PasserBy You mentioned that there was only one deduction guide in my first case. Is that because I was using the combination of aggregate initialization and explicit deduction guide which will stop the compiler generating implicit deduction guide?

@DanielLangr Yes, even though c++20 allows to use () for initialization of aggregates, the form Test t1(1.2); itself is not aggregate initialization.

Deduction guide works like a overload resolution for a function.
So when you have written deduction guide like this:
Test(int) -> Test<std::size_t>;

When constructing Test wiht deduction type, compiler will do:

find all list of deduction guides (you have one)
check if exact match of arguments types is possible (the is none)
check deduction guide can be used by promoting integer or floating point types (your case none) types of arguments.
check if deduction guide can be called applying some implicit conversion (here double -> int kick in).
if nothing worked try use deduce T by applying aggregate intilization.

So you have to create deduction overload which will kick in before conversion or promotion is applied. You need exact match. So solution is simple add template deduction gude which will catch everything else:

template<typename T>
Test(T) -> Test<T>;
Test(int) -> Test<std::size_t>;

https://godbolt.org/z/rhqP146jn
Now compiler when he can't find exact match without template, but can use tempted deduction guide which lead to perfect argument type match.

Thanks for providing the detail resolution steps. Do this resolution steps change if I use a constructor for initialization? I added a construction to the second program, and it works fine. I guess the type deduction works differently in this case.

TBH I do not sure exactly execution guide interact with constructors. I'm guessing first deduction guide must be considered then constructor is selected for given instance of class/struct template.

In the first case, what's allowing the code to compile at all, is the ()-initialization in main,
    Test t1(1.2);

which allows converting the double to std::size_t.
If you had used {}-initialization,
    Test t1{1.2};

the program wouldn't have compiled at all, revealing that you were trying to use an undeclared costructor.
In fact, even with your original code, Clangd gives the warning message Implicit conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned long' changes value from 1.2 to 1 [-Wliteral-conversion]                                                                                                                                              .

As regards the second case, you have indeed declared a constructor that matches exactly, thanks to CTAD, which deduces T == double, thus by-passing the deduction guide.
